# Convert Salesforce Lead with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, soap, salesforce

I am completely new to salesforce and its API(s). I have rails application with an existing users table. I need to start synchronizing data over to our new salesforce account.

Currently, I am trying to convert existing 'Leads' to 'Accounts'. As I understand it, this can only be accomplished with the old SOAP API. I am trying to use the [rforce](http://rforce.rubyforge.org/) gem.

I am able to authenticate according to the documentation, like this:

```
binding = RForce::Binding.new \
  'https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/20.0'

binding.login \
  'email', 'password' + 'token'
```

Then I try to call the convert lead action like this:

```
binding.convertLead "leadId" => lead_id
```

but I get the error:

```
:errors=>{:message=>"valid leadId is required", :statusCode=>"INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY"}
```

I know for sure that the leadId I am using is indeed valid, because I have actually retrieved it just prior to this call (using the REST API).

I believe that the problem may be that the rforce gem is not structuring the underlying SOAP call properly -- which I think is being described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10358532/1396827).

I appreciate any additional information anyone can provide.

Thanks very much,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Try using lead.Id instead of lead_Id.

Answer (score 0):

The input hash needs to have the key 'leadConverts':

```
binding.convertLead 'leadConverts' => { 'leadId' => lead_id, 'convertedStatus' => 'Status' }
```

You may need to add other arguments depending on what is required to convert a Lead on your Salesforce platform.